# How can I fetch a web page with external resources like browsers "save complete web page"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, web

How can I save a web page with external resources like browsers' "save complete web page" **but from command line or with node**?

That is executing `command /uri/of/page.html` saves all js and css files referenced in page.html.

Comment: How is this question node.js specific?

Comment: @CodeClown it is not, I meant a nodejs module to that is also ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use wget and its recursive download ability.

http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download

```
$ wget -r
```

or

```
$ wget --page-requisites
```